# Connecting two columns of the same table and comparing results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the table `CSBaumkontakt` and here is an exmaple query:

```
select rootpubindex
from csbaumkontakt
where dadpubindex = '2143640C-3ABF-440C-B094-2128F4495874'
```

with the results `rootpubindex` = `F7BC36A0-AD4F-49D5-B4FC-AD529C7EA738`

```
select rootpubindex, dadpubindex
from csbaumkontakt
where relpubindex = '2143640C-3ABF-440C-B094-2128F4495874'
```

with the result `rootpubindex` = `D66035CB-B7AD-4D54-9FC7-AE6E7F32662D` and `dadpubindex` = `D66035CB-B7AD-4D54-9FC7-AE6E7F32662D`

`Dadpubindex` of the first query is `relpubindex` of the second query.

Now I want to know if `rootpubindex` = `D66035CB-B7AD-4D54-9FC7-AE6E7F32662D`  and `dadpubindex`  = `D66035CB-B7AD-4D54-9FC7-AE6E7F32662D` from the second query are the same as the `rootpubindex` = `F7BC36A0-AD4F-49D5-B4FC-AD529C7EA738` from the first query. Therefore in this example no. Can I see this if the same or not for every row in the table with one query?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Ah, no boolean data type then. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in a tabular format* would really help me understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know whether exists a related record (`rel.relpubindex = main.dadpubindex`) with the related record's `rootpubindex` and `dadpubindex` matching the main record's `rootpubindex`. Use `EXISTS` for this:

```
select
  dadpubindex,
  rootpubindex,
  case when exists 
  (
    select * 
    from csbaumkontakt rel 
    where rel.relpubindex  = main.dadpubindex
      and rel.rootpubindex = main.rootpubindex
      and rel.dadpubindex  = main.rootpubindex
  ) then 'yes' else 'no' end as match_exists
from csbaumkontakt main;
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support the boolean data type, so we cannot apply `EXISTS` directly. I changed this to `CASE WHEN EXISTS ...`. Maybe the error related to this? Does it work with the altered query?

Comment: Yes it works now. Looks great. Thank you. I'll review now the results and look closer again at the query to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

seems that you are looking for the rows  with the same values in two column

```
select rootpubindex 
     , dadpubindex 
from csbaumkontakt 
where dadpubindex = relpubindex
```

of for see the match result

```
select rootpubindex 
     , dadpubindex 
     , adpubindex = relpubindex  /* 0 = not equal, 1 = equal */
from csbaumkontakt
```